# Is it possible to open the external browser from within a web page in StageWebView?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, stagewebview

I'm using Adobe Air 4 to build an Android app.
Is it possible to open the external browser from within a web page in a [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)? (e.g. the Android default browser)

Answer (score 0):

if i remember correctly, adding a target=_blank would open the current default browser on iOS -- probably on android works the same. but i'm not 100% sure :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for which purpose you like to open external browser, **for mobile**, StageWebView is **always takes system browser engine** to load html page. In desktop it supported by using StageWebView( true ). Please refer this link, you can find the solution.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html